# NestList with lower and upper limit

Tags: list-manipulation, graphics

I'm creating a series of centered lines in {0,0} tilted from a set of angles.

The first angle is $30°$ and the last one is $110°$.

I want to control the number of lines between these two angles, but I can not use `Subdivide` because the angles are not evenly spaced.

The idea is that each angle has a relative proportion to the previous angle.

I did a test with $quant=20$:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
quant = 20;
ang = NestList[#*1.067121 &, 30, quant]
p = FromPolarCoordinates[{5, # Degree}] &/@ ang // N;
Graphics[{Line[{{0, 0}, #}] & /@ p}]
```

[image: Imagem1]

And another test with $quant=10$:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
quant = 10;
ang = NestList[#*1.138747 &, 30, quant]
p = FromPolarCoordinates[{5, # Degree}] &/@ ang // N;
Graphics[{Line[{{0, 0}, #}] & /@ p}]
```

[image: Imagem2]

In both codes I had to test the values $1.067121$ (First code) and $1.138747$ (Second code) to reach the last angle of $110°$.

Is there something in "NestList" that I can increase?

If you have another idea outside of that, it is also an option.

**EDIT**

I tried this and almost got it:

```
Solve[Last[NestList[#*coeff &,30,20]]==110,{coeff}]//N
```

Comment: with `Solve` you should give the `Reals` domain argument, then select the positive result:  `Select[v /.  Solve[Nest[#*v &, 30, 20] == 110, {v}, Reals], # > 0 &][[1]] // N`

Comment: you can readily do this by hand though, with `v = Exp[Log[110/30]/20]` or even use `ang = #1 Exp[Subdivide[#3] Log[#2/#1]] &[30, 110, 20]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ClearAll[fun] ; 
fun[num_,rad_:1] := Block[
  {ang, poi, lin},
  ang = N[Map[Function[Rescale[Slot[1],{1,num},{30,110}]]][Range[num]]] ;
  poi = Map[Function[First[CirclePoints[{rad,Slot[1] Degree},1]]],ang]  ;
  lin = Map[Function[Line[{{0.,0.},Slot[1]}]],poi]
] ;
Graphics[{Red,fun[2,1],Blue,fun[5,0.8],Green,fun[7,0.6]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Image of output?

Comment: @MichaelE2, Done. Just noticed, this doesn't answer original question, sorry. Guess, this answer can be deleted.

Comment: Yeah, I was wondering if you got that. It's what I got, but sometimes there's an accidental mistake in the posted code.

Answer (score 3):

So the answer is:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
quant = 20;
ang = NestList[#*Exp[Log[110/30]/quant] &, 30, quant]
p = FromPolarCoordinates[{5, # Degree}] &/@ ang // N; 
Graphics[{Line[{{0, 0}, #}] & /@ p}]
```

Comment: @MichaelE2 I already did that, but I posted it wrong at the moment

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```
Block[{quant = 20, a = 30., b = 110.},
 ang = Exp[Log[a] + Log[b/a] Range[0., quant]/quant];
 p = 5 Transpose@Through[{Cos, Sin}[ang Degree]];
 lines = Transpose@ArrayReshape[p, Prepend[Dimensions@p, 2], 0.];
 Graphics@Line@lines
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Alternatives for `ang` and `lines`:

```
ang = Exp[Log[a] + Log[b/a] Range[0., quant]/quant]
ang = a (b/a)^(Range[0., quant]/quant)
ang = Array[Exp, quant + 1, Log@{a, b}]

lines = Transpose@ArrayReshape[p, Prepend[Dimensions@p, 2], 0.]
lines = Transpose[{ConstantArray[0., Dimensions@p], p}]
lines = Transpose[{0. p, p}]
```